# Azure: "WinHttpGetProxyForUrl failed" / System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-azure-federations

I am trying to update my Some 2500-3000 rows of my azure table1 in a federation. from table2 stored outside federation,in same DB .

When i run my worker role localy,i get the following error in azure-emulator :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):

A transport-level error has occurred 
when receiving results from the server.An existing connection was forcibly closed by the 
remote host.
```

followed by :

```
WinHttpGetProxyForUrl failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
```

Whats' happening here ?